# TypeScript and Swagger: create a generic GetManyAndCount class definition

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I've a collection of `Item` objects. From a REST API (using Node.js and Nest.js), I'm returning many objects and a count of all available objects in the database:

```js
type Response = {
  many: Item[];
  count: number;
}
```

I'm also using Swagger and a TypeScript codebase (I'm using Nest.js and its Swagger plugin).

Here, instead of using the `Response` type, I want to specify a class definition as a returned type on my API controller (`: Promise<GetManyItemsAndCountDto>`), so the API response is automatically documented in the Swagger schema:

```js
export class GetManyItemsAndCountDto extends GetManyAndCountType(Item) {}

export class ItemsController {
  async getItems(/* ... */): Promise<GetManyItemsAndCountDto> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Like here, in my project all APIs returning a collection of objects, are also returning a `count`.

How I can define correctly a generic and reusable `GetManyAndCountType()` class/function to get the response definition correctly documented with Swagger?

---

**What I've tried:**

- I tried the solution below using a mixin (inspired by [another use case](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/86#issuecomment-510927068)). The `GetManyItemsAndCountDto` is well created in the swagger json schema, but only as an "object" without its 2 properties: `many: Items[]` and `count: number`, which is useless.

```
interface IGetManyAndCount<T> {
  many: T[];
  count: number;
}

export function GetManyAndCountType<T>(ResourceClass) {
  return class GetManyAndCount implements IGetManyAndCount<T> {
    many: typeof ResourceClass[];
    count: number;
  };
}

export class GetManyItemsAndCountDto extends GetManyAndCountType(Items) {}
```

- For the time being, the only working solution I have is to create explicitly a class `GetManyItemsAndCountDto` (but I would like to find a more generic solution to avoid code duplication on several similar situations and APIs I have):

```
export class GetManyItemsAndCountDto {
  many: Item[];
  count: number;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar situation and explicitly using the `ApiProperty` it works:

```
interface IGetManyAndCount<T> {
  many: T[];
  count: number;
}

export function GetManyAndCountType<T>(ResourceClass) {
  class GetManyAndCount implements IGetManyAndCount<T> {
    @ApiProperty({ type: [ResourceClass] })
    many: T[];
    count: number;
  };
  return GetManyAndCount
}

export class GetManyItemsAndCountDto extends GetManyAndCountType<Items>(Items) {}
```

[image: Swagger image]

Cheers!